# Why is the output coming as 8883. How is the code is being executed?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, execution

Variable `i` is becoming `8` at the first entry in loop. Then how the condition `i <= 2` satisfied next time?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) 
   {
        int i = 8;
        printf("%d", i);
    }
    printf("%d", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int i=8` is a declaration of a new variable (declares and initializes new variable) which is in a local scope that shadows the existing variable from the more general scope.

In other words:

1. First `int i` defines variable;
2. `for` uses that variable and initializes it with `0` and starts a cycle;
3. `int i=8` - as it is written with `int`  - defines new local variable that because it has the same name that `i` from outer scope - shadows it ("shadowing" is a term). And so further code in the loop uses new local `i` which set to `8`.
4. Internal `printf("%d",i);` prints `8`.
5. Cycle ends and local scope gets erased, and so that internal `i=8` erased also.
6. `for` lives outside (in more general scope) of the scope of the loop. `for` condition uses variable from outside, which was set to `i=0` in step #2. So `for` in a second cycle instructed to increment (`i++`) it, so `i=1`, which passes the `i <= 2` check. So `for` indeed starts executing next cycle of internal code.
7. Inside `for` loop external `i` gets shadowed by internal `int i=8`... (step #3).

In short: It is because code declares a new variable with `int i`.

The good style is to:
`for(int i=0;i<=2;i++)` - always declare and initialize the variable in one instruction.

Comment: *The good style is to: for(int i=0;i<=2;i++) -* It is good style, but incompatible with the OP's intent to print the final value of `i` after the loop is done.

Comment: Using the `i` after the `for` loop does not have a sense in practice, `i` after `for` loop always would be `3`.

The person tries to understand what is happening with scopes and variable values, do not treat trial and error process as production code.

In practice programmers put `i` in `for` definition, since after the loop `i` value bears no info/use - it is `3`. If a number needs to be used - the definition of the boundary and use of that value is a more future-proof way. Aka `int const boundary=3`, `for (int i=0; i<=bundary; i++){}`, `... boundary ...`.

Comment: modifying `i` inside the loop body is not *good practice* but possible and attempted in the OP's code. In this case, the final value may be different and it is not obvious to beginners that it should be `9` if the local definition is removed. My recommendation would be `for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { /* do not modify i here */ }`

Answer (score 4):

It prints `8` three times from the loop with i = 0, i = 1 and i = 2.

```
for(i=0;i<=2;i++)
{
   int i=8;
   printf("%d",i);
}
```

The second variable `i` (the one declared inside the body of the loop) will not affect the first `i` (the one declared outside the loop), because it is declared in a different scope i.e., inside the loop.

Final the last 3 comes from because the inner most `i` will be increment on last time before exit the loop. So for:

```
printf("%d",i);
```

the variable `i` will take the value 3.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `i` you modify inside the loop body is a different variable from the `i` defined before the `for` loop and used in the loop tests.

`int i` defines a new variable only accessible inside the loop body, which is a block with its own scope.

Hence the code prints `8` 3 times, once for each iteration of the loop and `3` which is the value of the variable `i` of the main body after the loop.

Here is a modified version that will print `89` as expected:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        i = 8;
        printf("%d", i);
    }
    printf("%d", i);
    return 0;
}
```

It sets `i` to `8` and prints `8` inside the loop body for the first iteration, then `i` gets incremented, `9` is greater than `2` so the loop exits and `9` is printed by the final `printf`.